# embed python in android NDK

Tags: android, python, android-ndk

I have a android program that has main logic written in NDK. But now I want to evaluate some python codes as part of main logic. So I tried to use this embed python in c http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

I created a simple android project, with native.c like this (all I did was just adding python header)

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity"

void Java_com_example_com_test_mytest_MainActivity_helloLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring logThis)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char * szLogThis = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logThis, &isCopy);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szLogThis);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logThis, szLogThis);
}
```

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog `python2.7-config --ldflags`
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c  
LOCAL_CFLAGS := `python2.7-config --cflags`
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := -lpthread
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I got following error when compiling (using Mac)

```
Compile thumb  : ndk1 <= native.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-arch'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndk1/native.o] Error 1
```

Anyone could help please? :D

Comment: run python code within android ndk, wow! just for curiosity, what are you doing?

Comment: My main logic is written in C++. It works like an engine platform. Then I want to run python codes to do runtime logic so scripters will not worry about shits like memory leaks...

Answer (score 0):

Python2.7-config was built for a 64 bit i386 system not for Android.  It's passing bad arguments to the compiler in the LOCAL_CFLAGS field.  Either run one that you built to cross compile on Android or specify the values yourself.  Check google for 'Python-For-Android' (Py4A) on how to embed python in an NDK app.

Comment: link for Python-For-Android and NDK? I found it just for making Applications.